# How to specify a default value for VARIANT_BOOL?

Tags: com, default-value, idl

MS IDL has [syntax for specifying a `defaultvalue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366793.aspx) for parameters.
I tried to specify a default value for a function that accepts a `VARIANT_BOOL`:

```
[id(42)] HRESULT Foo([in, defaultvalue(VARIANT_TRUE)] VARIANT_BOOL bar);
```

And got the following error message:

> error MIDL2035 : constant expression expected

What is the correct syntax for specifying that the default value of `bar` should be `VARIANT_TRUE`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VARIANT_TRUE is #defined in WTypes.h.  You can't directly use it in your .idl.  The common approach is to simply use the value directly, like it is done in mshtml.idl for example:

```
  [id(42)] HRESULT Foo([in, defaultvalue(-1)] VARIANT_BOOL bar);
```

Or you can add a #define to your .idl if you prefer, put it somewhere near the top:

```
#define VARIANT_TRUE -1
#define VARIANT_FALSE 0
```

Comment: Did you know that using `TRUE` also works for `VARIANT_BOOL`? I'm curious as to which is the _official_ way to do this.

Comment: TRUE has the wrong value.  Given that mshtml.idl is a core Microsoft header file, I'd assume that -1 is the *official* way.

Comment: `TRUE` has the wrong value in C++, in IDL it seems that it has the correct value (see my answer). Regarding MSHTML.idl, where did you find it, I have the .tlh and .tli generated from the DLL but not an original .idl

Comment: In the Windows SDK include directory.  And no, midl doesn't magically change a 1 to a -1.  The only reason it seems to work is that most code will check for value != VARIANT_FALSE to check for true.  Or if (value) {}.  Sooner or later you're going to run into code that checks for VARIANT_TRUE.  Ouch then.

Comment: Found the idl. As for the value, try it yourself, it gets passed to C++ as `-1` not `1`.

Comment: Depends on the client runtime as well.  Interpreters use late binding.

Answer (score 1):

Although one should not mix up [`bool`, `BOOL` and `VARIANT_BOOL`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx) it appears that in idl `BOOL` is interpreted as a `VARIANT_BOOL` value.

```
[id(42)] HRESULT Foo([in, defaultvalue(TRUE)] VARIANT_BOOL bar);
```

When called from VBScript with no parameter specified this reaches the C++ code as `-1`.

I'm not sure which way is more idiomatic `TRUE` or as @Hans suggested `-1`.